# A single DTO with multiple constructors - does this seem like an appropriate solution?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, web-applications, architecture

I have an entity called "Set" which contains Cards.  Sometimes I want to see the entire card and its contents (card view), when sometimes I just want to know how many cards are in the Set (table views).  In my effort to keep things DRY, I decided to try and re-use my SetDto class with multiple constructors like this:

```
public class SetDto
    {
        public SetDto()
        {
            Cards = new List<CardDto>();
        }

        // Called via SetDto(set, "thin")
        public SetDto (Set set, string isThin)
        {
            var setDto = new SetDto()
                {
                    SetId = set.SetId,
                    Title = set.Title,
                    Details = set.Details,
                    Stage = set.Stage,
                    CardCount = set.Cards.Count
                };

            return setDto;
        }

        // Called via SetDto(set)
        public SetDto(Set set)
        {
            SetId = set.SetId;
            UserId = set.UserId;
            Title = set.Title;
            Details = set.Details;
            FolderId = set.FolderId;
            Stage = set.Stage;
            IsArchived = set.IsArchived;
            Cards = new List<CardDto>();
            foreach (Card card in set.Cards)
            {
                Cards.Add(new CardDto(card));
            }

        }

        /// property definitions
```

I originally had two different DTOs for sets - ThinSetDto and FullSetDto - but this seemed messy and tougher to test.  Does the above solution seem ok, or am I breaking a known best-practice? Thank you for your time!

Comment: If two different classes seemed messey, how does passing in a string which isn't used to bypass one constructor into another feel?

Comment: Why not use inheritance instead?

Comment: not right at all... thanks for the answer below.  Totally new to programming so that helps a lot.  Cheers :)

Comment: Why would you create Cards in the isThin ctor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create three methods in the SetManager class (a class handling CRUD operations) not in the DTO.

The dto shold have no such a logic inside. Anyway I agree with you that the replication is useless (and evil).

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I would prefer extension method by declaring all properties in Set class and modifying the properties by passing required parameters. Otherwise initialize a baseDTO and have various versions by adding required properties and call extension method to create required version DTO and return baseDTO.

```
public static Set SetDto(this Set set, bool isThin)
{

  if(isThin)
  {

  }  


   return objSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseSetDTO
{
  public BaseSetDTO()
  {
    Set();
  }
  internal virtual void Set()
  {
    //Do your base set here with base properties
  }
}
public class SetDTO : BaseSetDTO
{
  internal override void Set()
  {
    //Do a full set here
  }
}
```

Create a base class, then let your types handle what they are supposed to set. Create a new on for your ThinSetDTO and override again.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding how this would be used.  Can you give me an example of how both versions could be called from a controller?

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to this is to have the repository (or equivalent) return the 'flavor' of the DTO/entity you want by either having different access methods ie: `Get() ... GetSet()`, or to enumerate your 'flavors' of the entity in question and pass that to your 'Get' (or equivalent)  method ie:

```
enum ContactCollectionFlavors { Full, CountOnly, CountWithNames .... }
...
foo = ContactRepository.GetByLastName('Jones', ContactCollectionFlavors.CountWithNames);
```

This can get a little messy, from experience the entity in question should have some way of knowing what 'flavor' it is, which smells bad since it breaks encapsulation and seperation of concerns - but in my opinion its better hold your nose and keep some out of band data, so that later you can have lazy loading of the entity allowing you to turn 'light flavors' into fully populated entities.